# Make water transparent in the Google Maps API V3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm looking to set the "color" of the water to transparent in a way, that the div behind the map is displayed in these areas.

Is there a method of achieving this? I already tried the following, which doesn't work:

```
"stylers": [
  { "visibility": "off" }
]
```

it only sets the areas to some kind of nothing-color, but there's no transparency.

Comment: `transparent` is a valid CSS colour value, did you try applying that? (Not sure this is possible at all, but it's worth a try.)

Comment: no sadly it doesn't work...
if I set it to transparent it is displayed in the normal blue

Comment: It may not be possible, at least all I can see when Googling `Google Maps API V3: Make water transparent` is failed attempts... sadly

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that under the water still is another feature, the `landscape.natural`.

The following works for me up to zoomLevel 5:

```
          [{   //hide all fills
              "elementType": "geometry.fill",
                  "stylers": [{
                  "visibility": "off"
              }]
          }, {//and show the landcover
              "featureType": "landscape.natural.landcover",
                  "elementType": "geometry.fill",
                  "stylers": [{
                  "visibility": "on"
              }]
          }]
```

It may not be the solution, but it shows that it must not be impossible at all. Maybe you also find some settings for higher zoom-levels.

Demo: [**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/ME35L/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/ME35L/)

---

An approach especially for InternetExplorer (works on all zoom-levels).

Define a specific color for the water-feature(let's say #123456) and use the Chroma-filter for all images in the map:

```
#map_canvas img {
    filter:Chroma(color=#123456)
}
```

Demo: [**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/4V5U8/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/4V5U8/)